# laravel 5 - catch all route (Route::controller) at the end of routes.php?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

How can I use a catch-all route at the end of routes.php in laravel 5 like this?

```
Route::controller('{user}','PublicProfileController');
```

It 'destroys' the laravel debugbar and some javascripts in all views. This seems to work better:

```
Route::get('{user}','PublicProfileController@index');
```

I'm trying to have URLs like `mysite.com/username` with segments like `mysite.com/username/photos` or `mysite.com/username/posts`

Comment: `Route::controller('/{user}','PublicProfileController');` should be what you need?

Comment: seems not :( it breaks javascript photo arrangements across the website and the debugbar. if I #comment the line out, everything is okay again

Comment: Ok - so the problem is the profiler (and probably your photo package) register their routes *after* the `routes.php` file. So when you create a catchall route - its going to break any packages that register *after* `routes.php`.

Comment: Could you do something like `mysite.com/u/username` - like websites like Reddit do? Because you'll have to also prevent usernames that have route names in your application - i.e. `auth`, `login`, etc

Comment: ok. thank you. I have now changed to `site.com/users/username`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments this can be easily solved by just not using a catch all route. However there is another way.

The problem is that the routes of the packages get registered after the ones in your `routes.php`. You can change that by changing the order of service providers in the `providers` array in `config/app.php`.

Just make sure the service providers of the packages are listed before `'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider'` (that's where the applications `routes.php` is loaded)